# Laravel and eloquent returning results from a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relational-database, eloquent

In my website, I have a project table and that has a many to many relationship with another table project_user,

In the project table I would have a row that looks like this,

```
| ID  |  NAME       |
|-----|-------------|
|  1  | Project 1   |
```

In the project_user table I have some rows that look like this,

```
| ID  |  PROJET_ID  | USER_ID |
|-----|-------------|---------|
|  1  |      1      |    2    | 
|  1  |      1      |    4    |
|  1  |      1      |   10    |
```

The project model looks like this,

```
    class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'total_cost',
        'start_date',
        'finish_date',
        'sales_person',
        'project_manager',
        'client_id',
        'organisation_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function collaborators() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

And the model for the user table looks like this,

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
    }
}
```

What I want to know is how can I get a project from the database along with the user details for it's relevant users? I am currently trying this,

```
 $project = Project::whereHas('user', function($q)
        {
            //$q->where('user_id', '=', ResourceServer::getOwnerId());

        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your relation is `project` not `users`, so it's pretty straightforward:

```
$user->load('projects.users');

$user->projects; // collection of user's projects

$user->projects->first()->collaborators; // collection of users in signle project
```

If you want only one project, then you can do:

```
$user->projects()->find($projectId)->collaborators;
```

The way you tried will also work:

```
Project::whereHas('collaborators', function ($q) {
   $q->where( .. );
})->with('collaborators')->get();
```